# Kingfisher how it checks if need to refresh image?

Tags: ios, kingfisher

I'm using a [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) lib to manage images. The server refresh image every hour. Kingfisher not refreshing the image. Why?

**MY INVESTIGATION:** I've read [cheat sheet](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#cache) and [wiki](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki) and found out that the cache is marking as `expired` after 5 minutes for memory and 7 days for disk. When app did enter background and receive `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` the library performs `backgroundCleanExpiredDiskCache` that cleans the disk cache. Also there is a `.forceRefresh` option to load the image from web every time.

But i don't need to load image every time. I just need to refresh it when the new image appear on the same image url. How this works? I think it should be some field that received from the server, that can tell - you need to update your image, and the lib should manage this field, isn't it?

Comment: Your case is pretty unique so I assume you would have to handle the refresh policy in your app in some shape or form. If the server refreshes every hour then you can save the time the previous image load time and check it on app launch (or in other situations) and in the case that it's over 1 hour then try to force the refresh.

Comment: Every hour is as example. Actually it can refresh any time.

Comment: ah fair enough. Do you have access to the APIs you use in your app? Maybe like you said they should be modified to tell you that the images have been refreshed.